# merging changes in tfs

Tags: tfs, merge, branching-and-merging

We have a main development branch, which was branched for a release 1.0.  We also have branched the main development branch to do some parallel development.  A hot fix was done in the release 1.0 branch and merged up to the main branch.  Now parallel development is complete.  Everything has been checked in.  If we compare the main branch to the parallel branch we can see the differences.  We want to merge from the parallel dev branch down to main, but TFS is reporting nothing to merge.  What!?

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to do forward integration (from main to parallel) before you do your reverse integration (from parallel back to main).

Comment: I don't understand why this is?  Does this have to do with how the branches are set up?

Comment: The forward integration prior to reverse is always important. You may also want to try to do the merge with a brand new workspace and mapping.

Comment: I only want changes from my parallel development (new featureset) to go into main development (reverse integration), does tfs actually force me to require forward integration?  Why would I want my main development to get merged into parallel.  It seems like now there's two merge operations required just to get my parallel featureset into main.  is that right?

Comment: No, TFS doesn't force you to do this, but if you had 1.0 branched to main, you also need those main changes merged to parallel, or else your branches are out of synch.  Either way, you're going to have to merge, and it's usually better to resolve merge issues in your dev branch, instead of your main branch.  However, it could be that I'm just not grokking exactly what you're talking about with your branches.  That being said, try using a new (clean) workspace, and worse comes to worse, you can go to commandline and "use the force."